# Get all tileLayers from L.map object in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

What is the best way to access all displayed tileLayers from a L.map object?

Traditionally, I have stashed tileLayers in an object that I can access later, like so:

```
var mapLayers = {}

if (! mapLayers[mapId]){
  mapLayers[mapId] = L.tileLayer(url);
}
map.addLayer(mapLayers[mapId]);
```

This works well enough, but I keep running into issues with it, and it seems like bad practice to store this data in an object I've created when it's already stored in the map object.

Internally, the map object stores tileLayers in `map._layers`, along with other layers (grids, feature layers...).  They're indexed according to some internal leaflet scheme, so not sure if this is the best point of entry.

Using leaflet 0.7.3

Comment: Can you provide sample with issues as described below? I don't see why you would have more issues the way you do?

Comment: The issues are more in style than function.  As the mapLayers obj increases in complexity, storing stuff like layer order and other manually defined pieces of metadata, and starts needing custom methods for interaction, it seems that this functionality should be added to the map object itself, rather than a second object that references that map object.

Comment: I'm less interested in the issues I run into (possible to work w/ usually); instead, is there a better way than what I outlined? (updating the comment to provide a bit more context).

Comment: You are not alone in feeling that this hacky.  I have been working with L for awhile and I have simply written my own management.  The root of the issue is that everything in L is its own entity, especially vector data.  If you are coming from OL then throw that feeling that you are doing it wrong out the window. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try the `Map` class's `eachLayer()` method:

```
var layers = [];
map.eachLayer( function(layer) {
    if( layer instanceof L.TileLayer ) {
        layers.push(layer);
    }
} );
```

For complex cases you would end up writing your own layer switcher, and I don't see anything wrong with that. The Leaflet library aims to provide a minimum of core functions for an interactive map. If you need a bigger, all-in-one solution, try OpenLayers.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for (knew .eachLayer() was available to L.LayerGroup, but didn't stop to think about it in the context of L.Map.